I would like to reduce over a row in R
I do not write R very often, this is for a friend.
I have a dataframe full of strings, and I'm looking to convert each row of this dataframe into a document. The dataframe itself looks something like



name1
name2




jim
alice


toby
bob



I should be able to write a function:
f:rows->strings satisfying

f(1)="name1: jim\n name2: alice"

f(2)="name1: toby\n name2: bob"

I have never had so much difficulty getting a programming language to do what I want it to. Why can I not find a some sort of rowreduce function?

Do you just want something like: paste("Name1", df$name1, "Name2", df$name2) , which will paste together each part in order and produce nrow(df) strings?

No, I made my example with 2 columns, the actual case is significantly larger, and there are many different dataframes to apply it to. I am looking for a function that will fold a row.

You can also apply any function over rows apply(df, 1, arbitraryfunction), or write a loop for total flexibility for(i in seq_len(nrow(df))) {...} . You might have to expand your example to better represent the full complexity of the scenario if i'm still not thinking along the right lines.

Should it work only with a scalar index or also with a  longer vector? E.g. f(1) vs f(1:42)

Try stack + paste0
f <- function(k, dat = df) {
  with(
    stack(dat[k, ]),
    paste0(paste0(ind, ":", values), collapse = " \n ")
  )
}

such that
> f(1)
[1] "name1:jim \n name2:alice"

> f(2)
[1] "name1:toby \n name2:bob"

Data
df <- data.frame(name1 = c("jim", "toby"), name2 = c("alice", "bob")))


After extracting the row number n from the data.frame x, apply paste twice, once to paste the df's names and their values, twice to put everything together.
df1 <- read.table(text = "name1     name2
jim     alice
toby    bob
", header = TRUE)

f <- function(n, x) {
  stopifnot(nrow(x) >= n)
  nms <- names(x)
  row <- x[n, , drop = TRUE]
  y <- paste(nms, row, sep = ":")
  paste(y, collapse = "\n ")
}

f(1, df1)
#> [1] "name1:jim\n name2:alice"
f(2, df1)
#> [1] "name1:toby\n name2:bob"
f(3, df1)
#> Error in f(3, df1): nrow(x) >= n is not TRUE

Created on 2024-06-10 with reprex v2.1.0

Using sprintf in mapply
> f <- \(dat) {
+   mapply(sprintf, 
+          '%s: %s\n%s: %s', names(dat)[1], dat[[1]], names(dat)[2], dat[[2]],
+          USE.NAMES=FALSE)
+ }
> f(dat)
[1] "name1: jim\nname2: alice" "name1: toby\nname2: bob" 


Data:
> dput(dat)
structure(list(name1 = c("jim", "toby"), name2 = c("alice", "bob"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))


I have slightly modified the dataframe from a previous answer:
df1 <- read.table(text ="
name1   name2  name3
jim     alice  otto
toby    bob    klaus", header = TRUE)

If you want to use Reduce - it's possible. This is indeed an easy way to get all columns into one:
> Reduce(paste, df1)
[1] "jim alice otto" "toby bob klaus"

You only need to add the names to the values and then reduce, like, for instance, here:
reduce_row <- function(df, n){

  m <- Map(\(a, b) paste(a, b, sep = ": "), names(df), df)
  Reduce(\(...) paste(..., sep = " \n"), m)[n]

}

reduce_row(df1, 1)

Output:
[1] "name1: jim \nname2: alice \nname3: otto"

Note that the same effect has also do.call:
do.call(\(...) paste(..., sep=" \n"), m)

